# Estimating Regression Coefficients where parameters include linear combinations

Tags: matlab, regression, maximum-likelihood

I have a problem where I am trying to do normal multiple linear regression and estimate some parameters.  The model is

$\boldsymbol{Y}=X\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}$, $\epsilon \in N(0, I)$

I have 20 $\beta$ parameters to estimate and am using Matlab to solve using fminunc.

Now what I am looking to do is that instead of estimating $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ directly, I would like to multiply $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ by a matrix of constants, A (size 20 by 20), before doing the maximisation.

I would then like to find the new estimates, say $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ which could then be multiplied by matrix A to get back my estimates for $\boldsymbol{\beta}$.

The problem am having is that this does not seem to work, ie I cannot get back my estimates for $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ by doing this.  The matrix A is orthogonal, ie all columns are linearly independent.  There are 20 unknowns and 20 equations so why is this not working?

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to compute
$$\beta A=(\sum \beta_i a_{i1}, \sum \beta_i a_{i2}, ...)=\alpha$$
Then you multiply $\alpha$ with $A$ to get back $\beta$? No. You need to use the matrix inverse (which exists if $A$ is orthogonal):
$$\beta A=\alpha \iff \beta=A^{-1}\alpha$$

Comment: What I mean is that if you replace $\beta$ with $\beta A$ in the likelihood and maximise, then what you are really doing is maximising the likelihood over a new set of parameters $\alpha$.  Then in theory, to convert back to $\beta$ you would need to multiply $\alpha$ by A.  For example, if instead of maximising over $\beta$ you maximised over $\beta=2\alpha$ then the estimates are halved and to get back to $\beta$ you multiply $\alpha$ by 2.  This simple case works, but something goes wrong when a matrix A is used instead of a scalar.

Comment: First line was meant to say replace $\beta$ with $\alpha A$

Answer (score 0):

Maximum-likelihood estimators are [invariant under functional transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Functional_invariance), and so if $\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \boldsymbol{\beta} \boldsymbol{A}$ is a new parameterisation for your regression then $\hat{\boldsymbol{\alpha}} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} \boldsymbol{A}$.  Consequently, you have $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\alpha}} \boldsymbol{A}^{-1}$.